# Update particular values in a pandas dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting of a chat transcript:

```
id     time        author          text
a1    06:15:19     system        aaaaa
a1    13:57:50     Agent(Human)  ssfsd
a1    14:00:05     customer      ddg
a1    14:06:08     Agent(Human)  sdfg
a1    14:08:54     customer      sdfg
a1    15:58:48     Agent(Human)  jfghdfg
a1    16:18:41     customer      urtr
a1    16:51:38     Agent(Human)  erweg
```

I also have another dataframe of agents containing what time they initiated the chat.
For eg: df2

```
id    agent_id    agent_time
a1     D01        13:57:50
a1     D02        15:58:48
```

Now, I'm looking to update the values in 'author' column with the values in 'agent_id' based on that particular time, and also filling the in between values of author containing "Agent(Human)" with their respective agent name.

Final output desired:

```
id     time        author          text
a1    06:15:19     system        aaaaa
a1    13:57:50     D01           ssfsd
a1    14:00:05     customer      ddg
a1    14:06:08     D01           sdfg
a1    14:08:54     customer      sdfg
a1    15:58:48     D02           jfghdfg
a1    16:18:41     customer      urtr
a1    16:51:38     D02           erweg
```

I tried to do it using .map() operation

```
df1['author'] = df1['time'].map(df2.set_index('agent_time')['agent_id'])
```

But I'm getting a wrong output:

```
id     time        author          text
a1    06:15:19     NaN           aaaaa
a1    13:57:50     D01           ssfsd
a1    14:00:05     NaN           ddg
a1    14:06:08     NaN           sdfg
a1    14:08:54     NaN           sdfg
a1    15:58:48     D02           jfghdfg
a1    16:18:41     NaN           urtr
a1    16:51:38     NaN           erweg
```

I tried using .loc method too but didn't work

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve the desired output? Any leads will be helpful

Comment: What is `print (df1['time'].dtype, df2['agent_time'].dtype)` ?

Comment: @jezrael both are object datatypes, strings

Comment: except for those matching, all others are getting NaN, including, system and customer

Comment: Answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael You're the best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your solution should be added [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html) for forward missing values per `id` and [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for repalce non matched `Agent(Human)` to original values of `Author`:

```
m = df1['author'].eq('Agent(Human)')

df1['author'] = (df1['time'].map(df2.set_index('agent_time')['agent_id'])
                            .groupby(df1['id'])
                            .ffill()
                            .where(m, df1['author']))

print (df1)
   id      time    author     text
0  a1  06:15:19    system    aaaaa
1  a1  13:57:50       D01    ssfsd
2  a1  14:00:05  customer      ddg
3  a1  14:06:08       D01     sdfg
4  a1  14:08:54  customer     sdfg
5  a1  15:58:48       D02  jfghdfg
6  a1  16:18:41  customer     urtr
7  a1  16:51:38       D02    erweg
```